# justify text by changing the width of container

Tags: javascript, dom, text, width

I want text in my tooltips to be justified, but not as in css by making big spaces between words, but by adjusting container width.

For example here's the tooltip

[image]

I don't want my tooltips to stretch to 1000px if there is a lot of text, so I set max width to 300px.

By setting max width I get into situations where tooltip looked perfectly if I widened the container a little, in this case 15px.

Or there might be a case when I wanted to narrow the element for text to fit exactly.

What is the best way to do that ?

The best way I can think of is to get last word, wrap it in a span, measure the distance to the edge and if it's less than 50%, to widen or if more to shrink the container until container's height changes which means line was added or removed

Comment: Are you using jQuery (max-width implies that you are)? Also, if you don't add whitespace then perfectly justified text is unlikely unless total length of the words in lines all end up with the same length. You formula sounds similar to what max-width already does, i.e. tries to get as many words to match the length and then wrap if not. Or do you want an algorithm that will experiment with different lengths to find the optimal?

Comment: @Tomas - do you mean like this - http://jsfiddle.net/JrzY7/ - ( using `inline-block` to set the width based on the text up to a `max-width` and then, likely, `text-align:center` if it wraps ) ?

Comment: Calculating max-with as you describe [http://jsfiddle.net/36pq2/](http://jsfiddle.net/36pq2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/hLMkD/1/

It gets the real width of the String by injecting a hidden element and then sets the width of the tooltip to the width of the real string if it is in a defined range defined by `delta`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tooltip').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var delta = 20;

        // get the real width of the string
        var $tester = $('<div class="tester" />').appendTo('body').text($this.text());
        var stringWidth = $tester.width();
        $tester.remove();

        if($this.width()+delta > stringWidth) {
            $this.width(stringWidth);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope i could help a bit, needs a bit of fiddling i think but it should point you to the idea.

---

I thought this one over and came to the point, that a pure CSS solution might be what you are searching for. You can set the tooltip to `display:inline-block`, so it will only take as much place as the text needs (which solves your *narrow down* use-case) and then set a `max-width` to your desired width.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/hLMkD/1/ again.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/aslancods/jbGc6/7/

```
 /* css */
   body {
            font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12.6px;
        } // to make font proper


  .tool-tip {
            display: inline-block;
            word-break: break-all;
        } // tool-tip set to inline-block, so that it wraps text we can calculate text width

  /* tip-span class is added after setting width to tooltip */
  .tip-span:after {
                content: " "
            }
  .tip-span:last-child:after {
                content: ""
            }

<div class="tool-tip" id="tip" >
    Maecenas ultricies dolor id fringilla ornare. 
    Vestibulum quis semper quam, 
</div>
<div class="invisible" id="invisible"></div>

    /* JS */
    //get text inside tool-tip 
    var arr = $('.tip')[0].innerHTML.split(/\s+/); 

    //wrap each word with span and append to tool-tip
    for( i=0; i< arr.length; i++  ) {
        html += "<span>";
        html += arr[i];
        html += "</span>";
    }
    $('.tip')[0].innerHTML = html;


    // len = no: of words
    // get total width of text by calculating total tool-tip width 
    var tip_width = $('.tip').width();

   // find by which number, tip_width is divisible. it is the no of lines or no of rows of text
   // calculate width
   // width = ( tip_width + ( no:of words * ( width taken by a space ) ) ) / no: of rows
    for( i=2; i< len; i++ ) {

        if( ( tip_width % i ) == 0 ){
            setWidth = ( tip_width + (len * spaceWidth) ) / i;      
            if( setWidth <= 300 ) { // rows will choosen if it is lesser than 300
                console.log( i )
                break;
            }
        }

    }

  //set width to tool tip
  tip.css({ 'width': setWidth+'px' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of the string that you need and apply the needed format.

This is a really quick example of what im thinking. I wish i could elaborate, but you know, lots of things to do. Hope it helps.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tooltip">
            <p class="msg">Pork belly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <p class="msg">Pork belly synth narwhal meggings next level before they sold out Carles mlkshk chia Brooklyn</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tooltip">
            <p class="msg">Wes Anderson literally flannel Godard letterpress. Pinterest Carles artisan, PBR whatever cray cliche sustainable banjo fanny pack occupy Bushwick. +1 cred disrupt, DIY you probably haven't heard of them slow-carb blog authentic Portland </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="behavior.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Css**
    .container{
        width: 600px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

```
.tiny{
    width: 120px;
    background: #369;
}

.medium{
    width: 360px;
    background: #963;
}

.big{
    width: 600px;
    background: #693;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
$.each($('.tooltip'), function(index, val) {
    var msgLength = $('.msg',this).html().length;
    if (msgLength <= 20) {
        $(this).addClass('tiny');
    }
    else if(msgLength <= 100){
        $(this).addClass('medium');
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass('big');
    }
});
});
```

Of course it would be better if you do a function that you inmeddiatly apply after de tooltip is injected into the dom. :)

Just want to show some direction.

Tell me what happened.

Answer (score 0):

New here, but have been coding for 20 years. My answer falls in the category of "Maybe dont do that, try this instead".

Is there any particular reason you want to customize the width that carefully? Getting the required space for a particular piece of text is not easy, particularly if you have to support multiple browsers and operating systems.

I recently had to add tooltips to a custom webpage within Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The page was ASP, the default tooltip was awful. I played around with jquery for a while and got nowhere.

I found tooltip.js from MenuCool, and implemented it quickly and easily. Tried it for free, showed it to my boss. She liked it. Was 20 bucks for a license on one domain and all its subdomains.

After dropping the css and js files in the appropriate folders and adding them to the page like this:

```
<script src="Scripts/tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="Styles/tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I could then code the popup like this:

```
onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, this.value)"
```

Easy, and a nice looking popup. It seems quite customizeable, but I didnt bother with that myself.

Comment: This answer doesn't attempt to solve the question at all, and doesn't even give a compelling reason to "don't do that": there are several methods (as demonstrated by the other answers) of determining the width accross an acceptable range of systems. The OP also presumably has a tooltip system in place: spending more than half the post on a paid-for tooltip plugin you admit not having explored fully is off-topic.
A suggestion of how variable-width tooltips might hurt UI, or an explanation of how this or some other plugin helps solve this question would go a long way to making the answer better.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Determining the appropriate number of pixels required to contain a given block of text is extremely difficult even if the operating system and browser are known. My expertise is not in js, I tinkered with it for a day and was happy to find a tool that meant I could stop tinkering. I will be more careful about posting, and will try to give better suggestions going forward.